# How to reduce the number of OLL for a Cube

Tags: rubiks-cube

I use Fredrich methods to solve a $3 \times 3 \times 3$ Rubiks Cube but there are almost 54 OLL algorithms and I was wondering if there is a better method with less OLL algortim?

When I solve the first 2 layers what method should I use instead of using 54 OLL algorithms?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Two-Look OLL**.

Instead of orienting the complete last layer with one algorithm, you can orient it in two steps. First you orient the edges (3 cases), then all corners (7 cases). This gives you only 10 algorithms to learn.

You can find more details and algorithms here: [Cubefreak | Four-Look Last Layer](http://cubefreak.net/speed/beginner/fourlook.php)

Comment: I just read the link. How can we know which one of the 3 algortim to use to orientate the edges?

Comment: @OlePetersen You hold the last (unsolved) layer so, that it is pointing to the top. Then in the first step, you ignore all corner pieces. Concentrate only on the four edges. Here you can have four cases. It's possible, that all four edges are oriented correctly (all yellow stickers point upwards, assuming yellow is the color of your last layer). So you can see a plus sign (ignoring the corner pieces). In this case, you have nothing to do. In the second case, you only two opposite edges are oriented. Hold it so, that you see a minus sign and apply FRUR'U'F'. And so on.

Comment: @OlePetersen I hope you get the concept. Otherwise, watch a video. You can find a lot of different videos explaining the concept and the algs. E.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yxSHkyirDTk