# What are the specific algorithms Feliks Zemdegs uses to solve a 3x3x3 Rubik's cube?

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles

I apologise if this is not the right site to post this kind of question, but out of all SE sites this one yielded the most question concerning specific cubing algorithms (namely [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67958/how-do-i-solve-the-top-yellow-layer-of-the-rubiks-cube), [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41645/how-to-reduce-the-number-of-oll-for-a-cube), [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86935/rubiks-cube-2-look-pll-name-of-this-algorithm), [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64536/rubiks-cube-4x4-parity-moves) and [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/54056/rubiks-cube-last-edge-problems-beginners-method)).

I want to improve my speedcubing time (16.00), I was learning the Zborowski-Bruchem method because it has the least steps. I learned ~120 of the ZBLS algorithms but then I noticed that the top speedcubers don't use it (according to a post I read, it takes longer to identify the correct algorithm, compared to other methods).

I want to learn the same method as Feliks because even if he doesn't hold the world record right now, he has the most consistent short solve time. [A similar question has been posted in Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-does-Felix-Zemdegs-solve-the-3x3x3-cube) but I want to know 2 things:

1. What are the exact versions of the algorithms Feliks uses? I ask this because there are some algorithms that are better than others (in my personal experience I changed one of the OLL algorithms for the "I" shape in the past because I found one that was much better)
2. Does he really use VLS and ZBLL as the answer in Quora claims? I thought you needed ZBLS to be able to use ZBLL unless you get lucky. Also I thought that the winter variation (mentioned as one of the methods) was already included in VLS.

I understand that this information might not be easy to find... I do prefer Feliks, but if you have the algorithms used by any other top speedcubers they would also be most welcome.

Comment: I don't think there are many speedcubers here. You are more likely to find useful answers in the [Speedsolving forums](https://www.speedsolving.com/forums/).

Comment: Thank you for the reference! I'll leave this question here though, just in case someone knows.